# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 60f0d02f36ee6f2e505369e8" (type string) at path "_id" for model "collection"

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
app.get("/posts/:postId", function (req, res) {
let requestedPostId = req.params.postId;

Post.findById(requestedPostId, function (err, post) {
    if (!err) {
       res.render("post", { postTitle:post.title, postBody:post.content });
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
 });
});
```

This is the error I'm getting：

[image]

When I tried putting the existing _id of the document from the database in '''requestedPostId variable''' , then the code is working fine and the page gets loaded perfectly.

I mean to say that the database is not able to fetch data due to some casting error of objectId.

Can someone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a space at the beginning of your id

Comment: can u specify where?

Comment: `" 60f0...` as you can see

Comment: Why the space gets added here? In the database there is no space in objectId.
 So how to get rid of this unwanted space?

Comment: Thanks. 
My bad!
I had added a space in the URL of href in .ejs file.

Answer (score 0):

```
There's a Space in the ID being added, You can remove it, or add the trim function before doing the update.

app.get("/posts/:postId", function (req, res) {
let requestedPostId = (req.params.postId).trim();

Post.findById(requestedPostId, function (err, post) {
    if (!err) {
       res.render("post", { postTitle:post.title, postBody:post.content });
    } else {
        console.log(err);
    }
 });
});
```